# Performing actions based on UIGesture Recognizer States

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

The idea is to have processes attaches to UIGestureRecognizer states more specifically what I want is to record the gesture parameters into a mutable array, when the gesture state is recognized and when the gesture is ended output the mutable array.

Initially I thought I could use two while loops :

```
-(void)pincherAction:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{  
   if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
   {
      pinchGesture = YES;
      while (pinchGesture) 
      {
         if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
         {
             pinchGesture = NO;
         } else {
            //do array stuff here
         }
      }
   }

   if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
   {
        pinchGesture = NO;
        while (!pinchGesture) 
        {
            if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
            {
                pinchGesture = YES;
            } else {
                 //output array here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that once in the while loop it doesnt pick up any state changes. Would I need to run this loop on a separate thread? or am I doing something fundamentally wrong!?

Comment: I think you've got something wrong. Don't use a while loop to check for the states, instead the change of state is signaled by sending the pincherAction message again.

Comment: ok, but I need to loop the action until the state changes,that is keep adding to the array while the gesture is active and then looping the output when the state changes to ended, that is until the gesture is recognized as beginning again, sort of a constant push and pull

Comment: what are you storing in your array? I don't think that a while loop is the right approach. It puts heavy load on the CPU.

Comment: Im storing  a load of NSNumbers, basically the output of the gesture recognizer so in this case sender.scale

Comment: Can't you crate mutablearray as instance variable in view class? Then on StateBegan alloc new array, fill it till StateEnded and do what you want with saved output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a simple project with a UIPinchGestureRecognizer. Setting it up in the awakeFromNib for a viewController:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                              action:@selector(pinchAction:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rec];
    [rec release];
}

- (void)pinchAction:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%f %f %d", sender.velocity, sender.scale, sender.state);
}
```

Now, when I just do some pinching and move the two points around for a small around the pinchAction method is called very often:

```
2011-05-24 12:40:28.609 Pinch[1216:207] -3.506220 1.430036 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.625 Pinch[1216:207] -2.277907 1.381398 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.642 Pinch[1216:207] -2.738462 1.347324 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.659 Pinch[1216:207] -2.095164 1.308440 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.676 Pinch[1216:207] -2.383961 1.264628 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.692 Pinch[1216:207] -2.357965 1.240309 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.726 Pinch[1216:207] -1.192955 1.225726 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.760 Pinch[1216:207] -0.397422 1.215989 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.776 Pinch[1216:207] -0.291231 1.211164 2
2011-05-24 12:40:28.793 Pinch[1216:207] -0.366087 1.201407 2
2011-05-24 12:40:29.094 Pinch[1216:207] -0.366087 1.201407 3
```

And a change in state is recognized immediately. However it only records changes when you move around the fingers.

You don't need the while loop.

Comment: many thanks , I can see where Im going wrong and this certainly is the way I will record entries into the array. However when the state ends I want the array contents to output and loop round until the gesture is recognized again, a while loop is obviously a bad move, just trying to see how I would do this.

Comment: @coasty if you need something done on a regular basis try an NSTimer.